# Only execute method if ScrollView is not being scrolled

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack

I'm working with a view that contains a vertical `ScrollView` an `HStack` reflecting similar dates (they are both separate components though). When the vertical `ScrollView` is scrolled, I am highlighting corresponding dates in the `HStack` using `onAppear` on the `Text` elements in `ScrollView`. This works because the elements are inside a `LazyVStack`.

I also want to allow user to manually tap on an element in the `HStack` which should trigger the scroll to that element. I'm using `ScrollViewReader` to achieve this.

My problem is that this causes a cyclic block where a manual vertical scroll triggers highlighting in the `HStack` which triggers a scroll again and user ends up with jittery scrolling.

To fix this I'm looking for a way to know if the `ScrollView` is currently scrolling so I don't call the `scrollTo` method when a different element gets highlight in the `HStack`.

Keeping the `scrollviewOffset` doesn't help because it wouldn't tell if the `ScrollView` is still being scrolled at the moment.

Comment: You could disable the onAppear for while (0.5 sec) after something was selected in the HStack, to just give the scrollView time to finish scrolling.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500827/7129318) help? See the part after the edit. It sets up a publisher that reads whether the view is scrolling or not and gives you a value that you can check in an `.onReceive()`. In this case, it raises a flag that prevents another operation while the scrolling is happening and for 0.2 seconds after.

Comment: @ChrisR that's actually what I ended up doing. I toggled a `Bool` on the HStack's tap, for 0.35 sec (animation's default duration), and that helps me identifying if I need to ignore any changes during that time.