# SwiftUI not maintaining horizontal scroll position in nested list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been looking into this after solving this issue on my Android App using `savedInstanceState` and some custom adapter work. I have a nested view (vertical with horizontal scrollviews contained within) and noticed while scrolling that the horizontal lists will reset to an index of 0 once the view is off the screen and more than likely recycled.

I have looked into `ScrollViewReader` but could not figure out how to listen to the currently viewable index range ( in order to reset it later ). The other option seems to be using `GeometryReader` to do some view calculation, but that seems a bit off while using `LazyGrids`.

An example of the view that I am describing:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
            VStack {
                HStack {
                        // header stuff
                    }
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {

                        // Vertical list
                        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 17) {
                            ForEach(parentData, id: \.key) { parent in
                                Text(parent.title)
                                ZStack {
                                    Image("image")
                                    ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                            
                                            // Horizontal lists
                                            LazyHGrid(rows: gridItemLayout, spacing: 20){
                                                ForEach(data, id: \.key) { data in
                                                    Button(action: {
                                                        //action
                                                    }) {
                                                        FeaturedCellView(data: data).equatable()
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Examples of the views saving states can be found in apps like Netflix, or even in the App Store's horizontal grids.

I was hoping someone had solved this before and if so what you did.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [this answer after the edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500827/7129318). It was designed to scroll a list when the keyboard appeared. but it is the same general idea. All you need to do is store a cell that is in a known position in `@AppStorage`, and scroll there when you come back to the screen. One caveat, if you use `.onAppear()` to do this, it fires before the view is actually on screen, so you need to use a `DispatchQueue.AsyncAfter()` to make it wait, otherwise no scrolling will occur.